# validating against a JSON schema containing multiple schema definitions

Tags: json, postman, jsonschema

I'm creating a JSON schema for use in Postman that has a few schema definitions in them. The JSON I validate against the schema needs to match with one of the schema definitions.

**SAMPLE SCHEMA**

```
{
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/schema1"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/schema2"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/schema3"
    }
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "schema1": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "propertyA": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "propertyA"
      ]
    },
    "schema2": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "propertyB": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "propertyB"
      ]
    },
    "schema3": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "propertyC": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "propertyC"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**SAMPLE JSON DATA**

This JSON gets validated against the schema and correctly marked as invalid (because a string is needed):

```
{
    "propertyA": 123
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**

This example returns 4 errors according to https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/:

- Message: JSON is valid against no schemas from 'oneOf'. Schema path:
  #/oneOf
- Message: Invalid type. Expected String but got Integer. Schema path:
  #/definitions/schema1/properties/propertyA/type
- Message: Required properties are missing from object: propertyC.
  Schema path: #/definitions/schema3/required
- Message: Required properties are missing from object: propertyB.
  Schema path: #/definitions/schema2/required

I'm only interested in the error message saying that it expected a String.
How do I avoid those other error messages while keeping the schema definitions in 1 single file?

Comment: imagine you have a schema like oneof string, number  but gut null . Which error would you want the validation to throw ? its the same logic , the validation doesn't know which one you are interested in as everything is invalid

Comment: @PDHide I understand from your comment that the validation doesn't know what schema to validate against and thus validates against all schemas. So I guess the real question is, how to avoid such situation. Jason Desrosiers answer seems promising in addressing that.

Comment: Yes it's really good answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, `oneOf` is terrible for this kind of thing. `if`/`then` is verbose, but gives you much better results. Basically, you need to identify some condition that determines whether the schema should apply to the instance.

Usually, that condition is the value of a common field. In this case, if the instance being validated is an object with `"type": "A"` then it has to validate against the `/definitions/a` schema. If it has `"type": "B"` then it has to validate against the `/definitions/b` schema.

```json
{
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "type": { "const": "A" }
        },
        "required": ["type"]
      },
      "then": { "$ref": "#/definitions/a" }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "type": { "const": "B" }
        },
        "required": ["type"]
      },
      "then": { "$ref": "#/definitions/b" }
    }
  ]
}
```

If your condition is the presence of a specific field, you can use the `dependencies` keyword as a shortcut. If the instance being validated is an object with a "propertyA" property, then the instance must be valid against the `/definitions/a` schema. Likewise for "propertyB".

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "propertyA": { "$ref": "#/definitions/a" },
    "propertyB": { "$ref": "#/definitions/b" }
  }
}
```

---

There's actually a super simple solution for your example, but I answered for the general case because I assume your actual schema is more complicated than the example.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "propertyA": { "type": "string" },
    "propertyB": { "type": "string" },
    "propertyC": { "type": "string" }
  },
  "oneOf": [
    { "required": ["propertyA"] },
    { "required": ["propertyB"] },
    { "required": ["propertyC"] }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Great answer Jason :-). You guessed correctly, my real schema is a bit more complex. I probably simplified my example a bit too much. I'll need to identify multiple fields before I can be sure about what schema I need to validate against. I think the if/then keywords is indeed what I needed. I'll try it out and mark your answer if it worked out OK.